# How to reduce the size of HTML element that takes too much space-

Tags: html, css, size, element

I want two divs on my page to be aligned, I have set the {display:inline-block;} in the css of both elements but it still didn't work, I looked up in chrome and I found out that the size of the element is enormous (900x330), and it's probably what's stopping the elements from getting aligned

HTML:

```
<div id="shopmain" align="center" style="margin-bottom:30px;margin-top:10px;align-items: center;">

    <div id="shop1" width="25%">

        <img id="1" src="images/shop/1/1-1.jpg" style="width:20%">

        <p style="color:#974A2B;margin-bottom:1px;">TRIANGLE I</p>
        <p style="color:#974A2B;margin-top:1px;">88,99€</p>

        <button style="height:15px;width:15px;padding:0;border:none;background:none;" id="button1-1" onclick="document.getElementById('1').src='images/shop/1/1-1.jpg'">1-1</button>

            <script type="text/javascript">
            var buttons = document.getElementById("button1-1");
            buttons.innerHTML = '<img src="images/shop/1/1-1c.jpg" />';
            </script>

        <button style="height:15px;width:15px;padding:0;border:none;background:none;" id="button1-2" onclick="document.getElementById('1').src='images/shop/1/1-2.jpg'">1-2</button>

            <script type="text/javascript">
            var buttons = document.getElementById("button1-2");
            buttons.innerHTML = '<img src="images/shop/1/1-2c.jpg" />';
            </script>

        <button style="height:15px;width:15px;padding:0;border:none;background:none;" id="button1-3" onclick="document.getElementById('1').src='images/shop/1/1-3.jpg'">1-3</button>

            <script type="text/javascript">
            var buttons = document.getElementById("button1-3");
            buttons.innerHTML = '<img src="images/shop/1/1-3c.jpg" />';
            </script>

        <button style="height:15px;width:15px;padding:0;border:none;background:none;" id="button1-4" onclick="document.getElementById('1').src='images/shop/1/1-4.jpg'">1-4</button>

            <script type="text/javascript">
            var buttons = document.getElementById("button1-4");
            buttons.innerHTML = '<img src="images/shop/1/1-4c.jpg" />';
            </script>

    </div>
    <div id="shop2" width="25%">

        <img id="2" src="images/shop/2/2-1.jpg" style="width:20%">

        <p style="color:#974A2B;margin-bottom:1px;">TRIANGLE II</p>
        <p style="color:#974A2B;margin-top:1px;">88,99€</p>

        <button style="height:15px;width:15px;padding:0;border:none;background:none;" id="button2-1" onclick="document.getElementById('2').src='images/shop/2/2-1.jpg'">2-1</button>

            <script type="text/javascript">
            var buttons = document.getElementById("button2-1");
            buttons.innerHTML = '<img src="images/shop/2/2-1c.jpg" />';
            </script>

        <button style="height:15px;width:15px;padding:0;border:none;background:none;" id="button2-2" onclick="document.getElementById('2').src='images/shop/2/2-2.jpg'">2-2</button>

            <script type="text/javascript">
            var buttons = document.getElementById("button2-2");
            buttons.innerHTML = '<img src="images/shop/2/2-2c.jpg" />';
            </script>

        <button style="height:15px;width:15px;padding:0;border:none;background:none;" id="button2-3" onclick="document.getElementById('2').src='images/shop/2/2-3.jpg'">2-3</button>

            <script type="text/javascript">
            var buttons = document.getElementById("button2-3");
            buttons.innerHTML = '<img src="images/shop/2/2-3c.jpg" />';
            </script>

    </div>

</div><br/>
```

CSS:

```
#button1-1 {display:inline-block;} 
#button1-2 {display:inline-block;} 
#button1-3 {display:inline-block;} 
#button1-4 {display:inline-block;} 
#button2-1 {display:inline-block;} 
#button2-2 {display:inline-block;} 
#button2-3 {display:inline-block;} 
#shopmain {display:inline-block;} 
#shop1 {display:inline-block;margin-right:10px;margin-left:10px;} 
#shop2 {display:inline-block;margin-right:10px;margin-left:10px;}
```

If it can help, the default sizes of all the images is 900x1350 but the image is displayed as 180x270 on the screen.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you could post a pen so we could see the problem. However, my suggestion is to use max-width instead of width.